Como activar UPnP y NAT abierta en router optictimes
No encuentro la opción para activar el protocolo UPnP ni la función de NAT para dejarla abierta en mi router
Ya busqué en cada apartado de la Interzas de mi módem y no encuentro nada, espero puedan ayudarme
Adjunto imágenes de la información de mi router y una foto de el

